Why does asyncio.run() or loop.run_until_complete() run task that is created but not awaited?
Here is the code.
import asyncio

async def run_test():
    print("run1")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("run2")

async def main():
    print("main1")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(run_test())
    #task = asyncio.create_task(run_test())
    #task = asyncio.ensure_future(run_test())
    print("main2")

print("________________")
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
print("________________")

I'm expecting an output like
________________
main1
main2
________________

as the task is not awaited. But the output is actully
________________
main1
main2
run1
________________

And if I remove async.sleep() in run_test(), it becomes like this:
________________
main1
main2
run1
run2
________________

I've also tried
    #task = asyncio.create_task(run_test())
    #task = asyncio.ensure_future(run_test())

The result is the same.
3 questions:

Why is run_test() running without being awaited?
Is there anyway to create a task without putting it into the event loop?
Shouldn't run_until_complete() return immediately after main() completes?
My guess is that the event loop keeps running runnable tasks after main() completes and return when there were no more runnable tasks. But that conflict with the name "run_until_complete".
What is actually happening after main() completes?


I'm not super familair with asyncio, but create_task seems to run the coroutine. The corroutine then gets to the await, gives up control, and then control is passed back to main? I'm assuming.

@Carcigenicate Not quite; that would result in an output of main1 run1 main2. That's exactly how coroutines work in Lua and probably some other languages, but not Python.

A "single iteration of the event loop" (referred to as run_once()) consists of continuously running every "ready task" until no ready tasks remain.
A "ready task" is a scheduled task which is not currently yielding (i.e. isn't awaiting asyncio.sleep()).
The function loop.run_until_complete(main()) works like this (in a nutshell):
task = self.create_task(main())
while not task.completed:
  self.run_once()

We begin the first iteration of the event loop with a call to run_once(). In this first iteration, the following happens:

main() is a "ready task", so it begins executing

print("main1") outputs "main1"
asyncio.create_task(run_test()) adds a new task to the loop. It is in a "ready" state
print("main2") outputs "main2"
main() returns, completing that task


run_test() is a "ready task", so it begins executing

print("run1") outputs "run1"
await asyncio.sleep(1) makes the task yield, returning control back to the loop. An attribute is set to mark that this task will become ready again 1 second in the future.


There are no more running tasks, so the first iteration of the event loop is completed.

Now that the main() task has completed, run_until_complete will not initiate another iteration of the event loop, and your program exits. Note that the run_test() task never got a chance to complete.

Thanks. This answer is excatly what I need.
